# Lancer ex 2008 CVT - Slow Down warning on display!

Tags: troubleshooting

Yesterday, i had the "slow down" warning on my display when i was doing above 180kmph on the motorway and i was no longer able accelerate. it was as if i was driving an electric car. Though after some time (maybe about 2-3 mins) it was back to normal. What could be the problem. My car mileage is 138000.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely cause is transmision fluid /oil temp was too high.The ECM slowed the engine until the temp was within limits.If you routinely run the car this hard you may need an extra transmission cooler.

Comment: so it normal? and how often shud i change the transmission fluid?

Comment: also i was driving continuously for about 500kms, just stopped for refuelling. cud that be reason for overheating transmission fluid?

Comment: Check the owners manual for extreme use schedule.

Comment: Yes the light coming on is normal for a vehicle that is being operated beyond its design limits

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a limiter most vehicles have limiters in them.